# How many distinct objects are in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, object, reference

I'm learning about objects and references in a beginner programming class that I'm taking at school, and I'm a little confused about what constitutes an "object". Specifically, I'm not sure how to determine how many objects are in a list of lists.

After executing the following, how many distinct list objects with the value [1, 2] are there?

```
lst1 = [1, 2]
lst2 = [[1, 2], list(lst1), lst1]
lst3 = list(lst2)
lst3.append([1, 2])
lst4 = []

for lst in lst3:
    lst4.append(list(lst))
```

Thanks for any help/clarification.

Comment: This looks like homework... What have you tried? What is your own idea? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of distinct lists `[1,2]` is **8**. We can calculate this by going over the program line-per-line:

```
lst1 = [1, 2] # we create our first [1,2]
```

Next we construct a *list of lists*, like:

```
lst2 = [[1, 2], list(lst1), lst1]
#       ^       ^
```

Here we have created two additional `[1,2]` lists (denoted with the carets `^`). The first by another `[1,2]` list literal, and the second by calling `list(lst1)`. The constructor creates a *shallow* copy of the list, so a new list `[1,2]`.

Next we make a *shallow* copy of `lst2`:

```
lst3 = list(lst2)
```

Here we make **no new `[1,2]` lists**: we create a new list with three elements, but these all refer to the *same* lists as `lst2`.

```
lst3.append([1,2])
#           ^
```

Next we add a *new* `[1,2]` to the `lst3`. So that brings the total amount of *distinct* `[1,2]`s to four.

Next we will iterate over the `lst3` and make a *shallow copy* of *every* element in `lst3`. Since `lst3` has four distinct `[1,2]` objects, we thus will introduce an additional four `[1,2]` objects:

```
lst4 = []

for lst in lst3:
    lst4.append(list(lst))
    #           ^
```

So we obtain in total:

```
Expression | Count
-----------+------
lst1 = ... |     1
lst2 = ... |     2
lst3 = ... |     0
lst3.appe. |     1
for ...    |     4
-----------+------
TOTAL            8
```

**Memory layout**:

after the operations, the memory looks like:

```
lst1 -------------+------------+-> [1,2]
                  |            |
        +---+---+-|-+          |
lst2 -> | o | o | o |          |
        +-|-+-|-+---+          |
          |   \--------> [1,2] |
          +-> [1,2]      ^     |
          |   /----------/     |
          |   |   /------------/
        +-|-+-|-+-|-+---+
lst3 -> | o | o | o | o---> [1,2]
        +---+---+---+---+
          /-> [1,2]
          |       /-> [1,2]
        +-|-+---+-|-+---+
lst4 -> | o | o | o | o---> [1,2]
        +---+-|-+---+---+
              \-> [1,2]
```

Comment: `^` is a *caret*, the carrot is a pointy orange root vegetable 

Comment: Just curious, what did you use to generate that neat representation of the memory layout?

Comment: @Sty: did the ascii art myself.